# Specifying column type for a particular column in read_excel package of R

Tags: r

I have about 20 columns in an excel file. I am using read_excel to read them into R as a dataframe. One column is being taken as Posix and I want it to be text.

I know that mentioning the types of all the column types would solve this but I wanted to see if I could mention the columns' name or something to specify that only that column should be taken as text

So if i have a columns in the excel as Name, Age, DOB, Gender, time of birth
I want to implement something like this

```
df <- read_excel("excel.xlsx", col_types = 'time of birth':"text")
instead of
df <- read.excel("excel.xlsx", col_types = c("text","text","date","text","text"))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a named vector as the argument for `col_types =`

```
library(readxl)

instead of:
df <- read_excel("excel.xlsx", col_types = c("text","text","date","text","text"))
try:
df <- read_excel("excel.xlsx", col_types = c("time of birth" = "text"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can. The documentation for `col_types` says:

> Either NULL to guess all from the spreadsheet or a character vector
>   containing one entry per column from these options: "skip", "guess",
>   "logical", "numeric", "date", "text" or "list". If exactly one
>   col_type is specified, it will be recycled.