# How to prevent the loss of leading zeros when importing data via read_excel?

Tags: r, readxl

I have a problem with detection of the column types when importing data into R using the `read_excel` function of `readxl` package.

There are lot's of Q&As that are similar to my issue like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31633891/specifying-column-types-when-importing-xlsx-data-to-r-with-package-readxl) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55541106/specifying-column-type-for-a-particular-column-in-read-excel-package-of-r).

However I am still struggling.

Assume, I have an `.xls` file with just a one column `INN`  that contains digits only; however, it needs to be imported as character type (as the data could start with 0, and the 0 is very important).

Here is the code I used:

```
data = read_excel('data.xls', col_types = c('text'))
```

When I import the data, it looks like this:

```
      INN
1 2123123
```

As a result `INN` detected as character however in some rows where `INN` starts with 0, the 0 is dropped which is unacceptable.

I want the output to look like this:

```
       INN
1 02123123
```

Any ideas how I could overcome my issue?

Comment: What about reading that column as numeric, format the numbers with `sprintf` and then change it to character, would that be an option?

Comment: zero should not be dropped or the whole first line is dropped. please describe your error.

Comment: @wernor thank you for comment. Could provide with some code example?

Comment: @gaut assume I'm trying to import data with 1 value of '02123123' in column `INN`. As a result of my code I got '2123123' (i.e. without zero).

Comment: @DavitBidzhoyan it is hard to do with no actual data, but this `sprintf("%08.f",data)` could be an example of filling your number with initial zeros and it returns an 8 digit character string.

Comment: The short answer is that you can't with readxl. See [this Github issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl/issues/389).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
XLConnect::readWorksheet(..., colType="character")
```